# How to change drive name

Tags: drive

My disk have 3 partition, one for system and others for store data.
I can change its label, but I can not change path for that partition.
My partition have a "work" label name, but I must input `/media/dd7e8652-201e-4ea6-bb9b-8469091ecb25` to access in command line.

How can I access via `/media/work` command?

Thank for any command and answer :-)

Comment: You can use Tab autocompletion to enter the name automatically if you want. For example, do `cd /media` and then do just `cd ./dd7` and then press Tab.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 some tasks can not be auto complete by press Tab key :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your fstab,Just edit your fstab.. here's mine.

NOTE: 
*The second colum is the mount path
**I use umask=000 because of folder permissions on Windows<>Linux

If you have trouble with umask here's a good article:

http://www.omaroid.com/fstab-permission-masks-explained/

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=25677686-3338-406d-bb07-bcf2584cb8d9 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,user_xattr 0       1
# /mount/DATA was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=79239C344158404E /media/DATA     ntfs    defaults,umask=000,gid=46 0       0
# /mount/VM was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=00602055602053A6 /media/VM       ntfs    defaults,umask=000,gid=46 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=dbca6161-c0ad-4646-8d49-6e5243433a76 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Now, the issue is i can use autocomplete in terminal but when i list files by `ls` command, it doesn't show anything, althought i can use file manager to view a lot of files :|